# How can I make the watch command interpret vt100 sequences?

Tags: linux, unix, shell, terminal, watch

Consider this simple example (which displays in red):
 `echo -e "\033[31mHello World\033[0m"`

It displays on the terminal correctly in red. Now consider:
`watch echo -e "\033[31mHello World\033[0m"`

It does not display the color.

Note: I am aware that it is easy to write a loop that mimics the basic behavior by clearing and rerunning. However, the clear operation causes the screen to flash, which does not happen under watch

EDIT: Originally this question specified escape sequences rather than vt100 sequences, but that is not really what I am after, and was solved with single quotes.

Comment: By using only shell builtins to clear and display the content, it technically won't flicker. Save the content into a shell variable, then `clear` the screen and `echo` the var:
`while sleep <time> ; do x="$( <command> 2>&1 )" ; clear ; echo "$x" ; done`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:**

More recent versions of `watch` support color. You will need to use an extra level of quoting to preserve the quotes and escapes in the particular situation of the example in the question:

```
watch 'echo -e "\033[31mHello World\033[0m"'
```

From `man watch`:

> ```
>   -c, --color
>           Interpret ANSI color sequences.
> ```

**Previously:**

From `man watch`:

> Non-printing characters are stripped from program output.  Use "cat -v"
>          as part of the command pipeline if you want to see them.

But they don't get interpreted, so I don't think there's any way.

Comment: I'm basically convinced it's impossible.

Comment: I believe a recent version of watch may have added color support, but I haven't located documentation.

Comment: @AmanuelNega: It works for me. I tried `watch git status` and `watch git log`. You didn't say which subcommand you tried or how exactly it didn't work for you so there's no way I can guess what your problem is. If you mean that you're not getting color then you need to tell `git` to output color when its output is not to the tty: `watch --color git log --color`. This is a typical behavior (try `ls | cat` vs. `ls --color | cat`, for example.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out.  I changed the config to always use color

Answer (score 13):

From `man watch` of **`watch` 0.3.0** on Ubuntu 11.10:

> By default watch will normally not pass escape characters, however if you use the --c or --color option, then watch will interpret ANSI color sequences for the foreground.

It doesn't seem to work with your literal string on my terminal, but these work:

```
watch --color 'tput setaf 1; echo foo'
watch --color ls -l --color
```

Comment: Its in the manpage for watch `man watch` on mac osx, but afaik it doesnt work .

Comment: This is giving me a headache!  <file> has colorizing codes scattered through out.    `tail -n 5 <file>` shows me a beautiful, colorful display.  `watch tail -n 5 <file>` shows me b/w output and I can see all the codes.   `watch -c tail -n 5 <file>` shows me b/w but none of the codes (which makes it easier to read, but I wanted color).

Comment: It turns out my prior comment is moot,  `tail` has an `-f` parameter that incorporates a `watch` feature that retains and colorfully displays any color codes that are contained in the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can try single quoting your command :

```
watch 'echo -e "\tHello World"'
```

On my machine this leaves me with a `-e` as first character, and a correctly tabbed `hello world.`
It seems `-e` is the default  for my version of echo. Still, it is a progress toward a correctly tabbed `hello world`

What happens is a double unquoting :
what watch see

```
echo -e "\033[31mHello World\033[0m"
```

what the shell called by watch see :

```
echo -e \033[31mHello World\033[0m
```

And then the backslash come into play, even when quoted, and it becomes a quoting nightmare.

Comment: In an attempt to simplify things, I have probably made things too simple.  You are right that this works and I have upvoted you for that, but what I am really after is getting vt100 codes to work correctly, which appears to be a different problem than just getting escape sequences interpreted.  For instance:
echo -e "\033[31mHello World\033[0m" does not work properly under watch even with single quotes.