# Colors with unix command "watch"?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, watch

Some commands that I use display colors, but when I use them with watch the colors disappears:

```
watch -n 1 node file.js
```

Is it possible to have the colors back on somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make the watch command interpret vt100 sequences?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417824/how-can-i-make-the-watch-command-interpret-vt100-sequences)

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Some newer versions of `watch` now support color.

For example `watch --color ls -ahl --color`.

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417824/how-can-i-make-the-watch-command-interpret-vt100-sequences).

If you're seeing monochrome output when you expect color, it's likely that the command you're running within `watch` is detecting that it's not attached to the terminal and you'll need to force color output. Some examples:

```
CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 watch --color ls -ahl    # MacOS
watch --color ls -ahl --color=always      # Ubuntu
```

For `ls` and other programs you may need to do other configuration, but that will show up even if you're not using `watch`.

Comment: take a look at: http://superuser.com/questions/125469/bash-watch-command-with-colors-preserved (first answer) - Maybe you can link it in your answer.

Comment: I came here to use `watch` with `git diff`. FWIW, to get that to work you have to pass in `--color=always` to `git diff` (e.g. `watch --color git diff --color=always`.

Comment: For gpustat, "watch -n 1 --color gpustat --color" works.

Comment: To show colors using `watch` with  `git status` need to use `watch --color git -c color.status=always status`. See linked answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47065/268780.

Comment: my watch claims to support --color (also -c) but the output is still black and white - even when using your exact example.

Comment: @AlRo, same issue on my side. Just curious, which OS are you on? I am seeing that issue on CentOS 7.

Comment: This also affects color of the terminal is it normal?

Comment: @alper: Can you be more specific? What part of the terminal? Is it after you exit `watch` or while it's running? Which OS, distribution or window manager? Which terminal (xterm, gnome-terminal, Terminal.app)? What command line were you running within `watch`?

Answer (score 59):

Do not use `watch` ... When you use watch programs can detect they're not writing to a terminal and then strip the color. You must use specific program flags to keep the control codes there.

If you don't know the flags or there isn't you can make a poor's man watch by:

```
while sleep <time>; do clear; <command>; done
```

It will have a bit of flicker (watch works "double buffered") but for some stuff it is useful enough.

You may be tempted to make a double buffered poor man's watch using

```
while sleep <time>; do <command> > /tmp/file; clear; cat /tmp/file; done
```

But then you'll hit again the "I am not writing to a terminal" feature.

Comment: Maybe use `while sleep <time>; do clear; <command> | tee /tmp/file; done` instead of `>` and `cat`?

Comment: mmm I don't get it @AndréLeria ... | tee will remove color codes like `watch` do and doesn't prevent command from flickering

Comment: It is a suggestion for the second example, which also doesn't give me colors. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @AndréLeria The second "example" is a wrong example (As its said in the las line). The point is that once you hit a pipe you lose the color codes since you aren't writing to a terminal. It is there to show how wrong is to try to compensate the flicker due the time lapse between clear and the target command execution using a pipe to work buffered like `watch`

Comment: In bash:
`while sleep <time> ; do x="$( <command> 2>&1 )" ; clear ; echo "$x" ; done` -- It uses only shell builtins to clear the screen and display the output, being therefore the least flickering alternative.

Comment: @GézaTörök, yes but this also clear the color codes from the result output, which was the main concern of the user asking.

Comment: @theist nope, variable `x` will hold special characters as well, except `\0`. Try this in bash-3.2 or later:
`while true ; do x="$( echo -e "\e[31;01m" ; date ; echo -e "\e[0m" )" ; clear ; echo "$x" ; sleep .1 ; done`
it will display red date :)

Comment: @GézaTörök Geez from some commands I tried works but others not... for example didnt work for `ls --la` (in my setup it adds colors by default) nor `ls | grep foo`  nor `grep ^ *` nor `bundle exec knife status` but worked for `ls --color` maybe because --color forces color codes

Comment: @theist sure, color codes must be emitted by the command. But when you are `watch`ing a command, does that process see so that it writes to a terminal? I don't think so. All the `grep` alternatives with `--color` added must work as well.

Comment: This'll keep blinking for short intervals.

Comment: The poor man's `watch` has the ~~bug~~ feature of also showing the history of previous invocations if you scroll up.

Answer (score 36):

While other answers solve this problem, the easiest way to accomplish this is using the [`unbuffer`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer) tool. To use it simply do:

```
$ watch --color 'unbuffer <your-program>'
```

This way you don't have to hunt for control sequence enabling flags of your program. The caveat however is that your version of watch should support the `--color` flag.

You can install unbuffer on Debian or Ubuntu using `sudo apt-get install expect`.

Comment: only you get my upvote. all the other higher voted answers did help me. this one did the trick

Comment: This should be accepted answer.

Comment: `brew install expect` for macOS.

Answer (score 20):

You can duplicate the fundamental, no-frills operation of `watch` in a couple lines of shell script.

```
$ cat cheapwatch 
#!/bin/sh

# Not quite your Rolex

while true ; do
  clear
  printf "[%s] Output of %s:\n" "$(date)" "$*"
  # "$@" <- we don't want to do it this way, just this:
  ${SHELL-/bin/sh} -c "$*"
  sleep 1  # genuine Quartz movement
done

$ ./cheapwatch ls --color  # no problem
```

Eventually, someone very clever will hack a `tr` command into this script which strips control characters, and then force the user to use `--color` to disable that logic. For the time being, the sheer naivete of this implementation is keeping the color-eating monster away.

If you're in a situation where `watch` doesn't have the `--color` option and you can't upgrade the package for whatever reason, maybe you can throw this in.

Answer (score 8):

YES

watch works with color output.
it is part of the procps package (at least in debian)
here is bugreport for your question http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=129334
where they answer, that you should update the procps package

e.g. with ubuntu 11.04 this package works http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/procps

tl;dr

update procps

Answer (score 7):

Other answers might not work if the command does not have option to force color output. Or you might be lazy like me and do not want to browse manual for each command to find the correct setting. I tried a few different techniques:

### The `script` command

Script command captures output as run by an interactive terminal session. With the combination of `--color` parameter of `watch`, it retains colors:

```sh
watch --color "script -q -c '<command>' /dev/null"
```

`-q` is for quiet, `-c` is for command and `/dev/null` is the log file, which is not needed as stdout also shows the output.

Edit: This is the best option so far, I left the earlier solution below for the interested.

### Earlier try: Rewrite the terminal window

As suggested by some, a simple while loop with `clear` and `sleep` can be used to run the command in terminal without capturing its output. This usually causes flicker, as `clear` removes all characters and then the command take some time to print the new output line by line.

Fortunately, you can fix this with some clever terminal tricks using `tput`. Just leave the old output visible while writing the new on top.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
trap "tput cnorm" EXIT  # unhide the cursor when the script exits or is interrupted

# simple interval parameter parsing, can be improved
INTERVAL=2s
case $1 in
  -n|--interval)
    INTERVAL="$2"
    shift; shift
  ;;
esac

clear           # clear the terminal
tput civis      # invisible cursor, prevents cursor flicker

while true; do
  tput cup 0 0  # move cursor to topleft, without clearing the previous output
  sh -c "$*"    # pass all arguments to sh, like the original watch
  tput ed       # clear all to the end of window, if the new output is shorter
  sleep "$INTERVAL"
done
```

The script fixes color problems, but a different bug remains: If the lines of the command output gets shorter, the rest of the line is not necessarily erased, so **the output might not match with reality!**

Comment: This worked for me. I wanted to show taskboard (https://github.com/klaussinani/taskbook) tasks in a tmux popup window with `watch` and this helped.

Answer (score 2):

From watch manual:

> Non-printing characters are stripped from program output.  Use "cat -v" as part of the command pipeline if you want to see them.

Though, I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: This causes the control characters to be visible in the output for me, rather than causing colouration. For example `watch -c "ls --color|cat -v"` shows `^[[0m^[[01;34mAgent^[[0m` for the first line.

Comment: try `watch --color ls --color=always .`

Answer (score 2):

[`unbuffer` is a great way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10832/209677) to avoid letting process know if it is writing to TTY, but worth noting that `watch` [does not support 8-bit colors and above yet](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/issues/44).

If instead of `ls` you use something more modern [like `bat`](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat) or `exa`, you should append `--theme=ansi` (not even `--theme=base16` works). `git log` works out of the box because it always uses 3-bit colors ([source](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/issues/1681#issuecomment-857053835)).

Example:

```
watch --color -d -n 0.5 'mycommand file | bat --color=always --theme=ansi'
```

Could also use `-f` instead of `--color=always`.

Another alternative could be [Pygments](http://pygments.org/).

Comment: that is kind of sad, because it does not work with kubecolor yet 