# Automatically run RSPec when plain-old Ruby (not Rails) files change

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am writing a Ruby script designed to run from the command line. The script has a corresponding RSpec file that verifies its functionality. The folder structure is:

```
./main_script.rb
./spec/main_script_spec.rb
```

Running `rspec spec` in the top level directory works as expected. Test results from the `./spec/main_script_spec.rb` file are shown. I'd like to avoid running this manually every time I change either the main script file or the spec file. All my search results turn up things like [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec) which (as far as I can tell) are all designed for Rails apps.

How do I setup RSpec to watch for script or spec changes and run automatically with non-Rails Ruby code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like David said, Guard can be used to watch a wide variety of files and perform actions when those files are modified. It does not have to be used with a Rails app. I have set up something similar in the past using `guard`. Here is what I did:

Place the following in your `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'guard'
gem 'guard-shell'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9'
```

Then run:

`$ bundle install`

Create a Guardfile in your home directory with:

`$ guard init`

In the `Guardfile`, comment out the examples and add this:

```
guard :shell do
  watch(%r{^*\.rb}) { `bundle exec rspec spec/` }
end
```

This tells guard to watch for modifications to any ruby files in the directory and execute the command `bundle exec rspec spec/` when they change (the backticks are used to execute the command in the shell).

Then open up a new terminal window in your current directory and start a `guard` server to start watching the files:

`$ bundle exec guard`

Now your Rspec test suite should automatically run when you modify ruby files in the directory.

Comment: I had to add some additional gem to get it to work on my machine (running Ruby 1.9.3-p392 and guard 1.7.0). I've updated the answer to include those calls. Once they were in place, it works great.

Answer (score 3):

I used guard at the past, but now I'm using a combination of [rspec focus feature](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/filtering/filter-run-when-matching) and watch command.

It's very simple, just add an `f` before a `describe` of `it` block you want to run the test. So it would becomes `fdescribe` or `fit` block. This is the same as adding a tag `:focus => true` to your block.

We can then filter specs with the focus tag: `rspec -t focus`

Now, to keeping running theses specs (every 0.5 seconds) with focus tag we call it with `watch` command:

```
watch -n 0.5 rspec -t focus
```

But with that the output won't show colors. So, we need to use with [unbuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793126/colors-with-unix-command-watch).

```
sudo apt-get install expect
```

With a little customization:

```
watch -n 0.5 --color 'unbuffer bundle exec rspec -t focus'
```

Since it's annoying to type this all, I made two alias at my `~/.bash_aliases` file (your can use `.bashrc` as well):

```
alias focus="watch -n 0.5 --color 'unbuffer bundle exec rspec -t focus'"
alias focuss="bundle exec rspec -t focus"
```

Now I can type `focus` to keep running it, or for a single focus execution I type `focuss`

Answer (score 2):

Guard can be used for plain old ruby.  I generally have trouble with guard so I like to use [watchr](https://github.com/mynyml/watchr), another gem.  With a few lines of code you can tell watchr to watch for changes to your files and run a command when they change.

For an example of guard with plain ruby, see the shuhari gem.

update on watchr gem: There appears to be [an issue](https://github.com/mynyml/watchr/issues/57) with this gem, perhaps with versions of ruby >= 2.0. The [observr gem](https://github.com/kevinburke/observr) addresses this issue and works as expected in ruby 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) and the [guard-rspec](https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec) addition with great results, and I don't believe it to be Rails-specific. Other Ruby/RSpec projects should work equally well.

The [guard documentation](http://guardgem.org/) recommends the use of Bundler and to "always run Guard through Bundler to avoid errors". I.e. you install it through your Gemfile and always run it with `bundle exec guard` (or use [rubygems-bundler](https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler) to avoid the bundle exec part).