# Can I get RSpec to only run changed specs?

Tags: git, rspec

I have a test suite for a very large project (~ 3800 individual examples) that I'm updating from RSpec 2.14 to 3.6.

I have just run a replace-all for `s/be_true/be true/`, but some of them should `be_truthy` instead, and these specs are failing.

I can extract the changed lines from `git diff` - with a little work - but then I need to feed these into RSpec's `config.filter_run`, and it doesn't seem to like me doing that for the `locations` filter (the one activated when you specify a `rspec path/to/file:line` on the command line); it says "`All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:locations=>...}`".

I can also `example.run unless example.location.in? changed_specs` in an `around` filter, but this `skip`s all the others and marks them as `pending`, rather than ignoring them completely; and it doesn't work in concert with the other filters to `run_all_when_everything_filtered`. (Probably because `example.location` refers to the top line of the test, but the changes are a few lines below that.)

And I can't seem to use it to add a tag to the `example.metadata` and then filter it out, either.

Edit: I also don't want to specify them on the command line, because my tests run under `rerun`, which keeps running the same command.

Any more ideas?

Answer (score 15):

You can run changed specs with:

```
rspec $(git ls-files --modified spec)
```

if you want include new unversioned specs as well use:

```
rspec $(git ls-files --modified --others spec)
```

You can make this handier with a shell alias:

```
alias rch='rspec $(git ls-files --modified --others spec)'
```

Comment: That's not bad either - considerably more compact than PressingOnAlways' answer, but I think it has the same issues

Comment: I added how to use an alias to make it even more compact.

Answer (score 5):

git status might be a better bet? Why doesn't something like this work for you:

```
$ bundle exec rspec $(git status | grep spec | grep "modified:" | cut -b 15-)
```

source: https://coderwall.com/p/usrhyq/running-modified-specs-with-git

Comment: Hmm. Not bad, but (1) I'd rather specify line numbers as well, and (2) I want my `spec_helper` to pick up the relevant specs, since - I originally neglected to mention - I have `rspec` running under `rerun`.

Comment: `cut -b 15-` didn't quite work for me (it cut the string in the wrong place), but `awk '{ print $2 }'` did. I think using `awk` is likely to be more reliable, since it splits the string based on whitespace rather than position.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a straight forward way of doing it, but you can do it combining the ruby gem 'guard' and the 'watch' command like mentioned in the below link.

[Automatically run RSPec when plain-old Ruby (not Rails) files change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974421/automatically-run-rspec-when-plain-old-ruby-not-rails-files-change)

It worked for me but you may need to find out further tweaks to enhance what you want.

Additional suggestion, https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec is having good support if you want to try out the above with 'guard-rspec' gem.