# Can rspec be configured to only run tests what have been modified within a single spec file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working with Rails 5 and rspec (gem version 4).  I was wondering if RSpec can be configured to only run tests that have been modified within a single file when only running that file, i.e.

```
bundle exec rspec spec/my_spec.rb
```

.  If my file is like this

```
RSpec.describe MyClass do

  context "context 1" do
    it "tests condition 1" do
    end

    it "tests condition 2" do
    end

    ...
  end

  context "context 2" do
    ...
  end

  ...
end
```

and I only update tests in "context 1," is it possible to test the single file and have only modified tests from within that file run?  With respect to this answer -- [Can I get RSpec to only run changed specs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45496443/can-i-get-rspec-to-only-run-changed-specs), it appears that only relates to actual files that have changed when running the complete suite of rspec tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for guard.

Checkout nicely written article https://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2017/02/09/guard-is-your-friend

Answer (score 0):

There is a Ruby Gem called [retest](https://github.com/AlexB52/retest) designed to do exactly that. Just run `retest`, and it will watch for changes in the code or the specs themselves, and rerun just the respective spec file.

Comment: It'll run the entire file? I normally use `guard-rspec` for this. But OP was ideally looking for something to run just the changed specs within the file.