# linux - watch not showing colors through ssh

Tags: python, linux, shell, command-line

I have a simple python script that prints text with color, using [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) package.

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from colorama import Fore

text = "Test"

print(Fore.RED + text)
```

Problem is -  when I try to put it into `watch` command **when connected via SSH**, it doesn't show the colors.

**when connected via SSH I run**

```
watch -c test.py
```

And it doesn't show the colors.

I searched a lot about this issue, but `watch` via `SSH` won't show colors for some reason. (also when using the `-c` flag).

What is the problem here?

**EDIT:**

Asked another question that reproduces the issue - [linux - watch command not showing colors via ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495237/linux-watch-command-not-showing-colors-via-ssh)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Colors with unix command "watch"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793126/colors-with-unix-command-watch)

Comment: Confirmed! Using colorama with watch and color flag - like you are supposed to -  results in uncolored text, see answer for workaround.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I am connected via SSH and it doesn't work. Edited the question.

Comment: Sry can't reproduce, that is most likely a problem with your terminal. I just sshed into my home server and run the script there with `watch -c "python test.py"` and I got colors....

Comment: asked another question that reproduces the problem here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495237/linux-watch-command-not-showing-colors-via-ssh

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** after William Russells comment I looked a bit around in the colorama github repo and found the `wrap` parameter of the [init() function](https://github.com/tartley/colorama/blob/master/colorama/initialise.py#L23)

By telling colorama to act like stdout is not wrapped by calling `init(wrap=False)`:

**test.py**

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
import colorama
from colorama import Fore

colorama.init(wrap=False)

text = "Test"

print(Fore.RED + text)
```

you get proper colors inside the watch command too.

---

**Update 2:** For colors over ssh in general see [How to get coloured terminal over ssh?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16336/how-to-get-coloured-terminal-over-ssh)

---

**Original answer:**

Ok I don't have any idea why but when I remove the `colorama.init()` it works:

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from colorama import Fore

text = "Test"

print(Fore.RED + text)
```

Called with `watch -c test.py` results in red "Test"...

I was copy pasting their sample from the python package index and forgot the `init()` and surprise I got colored watch output o.O

Comment: init() is probably checking if it is writing to a tty and disabling color if it is not.  When running through watch, the output of the wrapped program is not a tty, so init() disables the color.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I am connected via SSH and it doesn't work. Edited the question.

Comment: asked another question that reproduces the problem here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495237/linux-watch-command-not-showing-colors-via-ssh