# linux - watch command not showing colors via ssh

Tags: python, linux, shell, command-line

I have a very basic script named `colors` to print "HEY" in green and bold using codes around the text.

**colors:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

a = '\033[0m\033[32m\033[01mHEY\033[0m'

print a
```

the `\033[01m` is making the text bold.

the `\033[32m` is making the text green.

the `\033[0m` should be around the text in both sides.

- When I run the script on my machine - it prints in **bold and
  green**.
- When I run the script on my machine **with watch** (`watch -c
  colors`) - it prints in **bold and green**.
- When I run the script on a server **via SSH** - it prints in **bold
  and green**.
- When I run the script on a server **with watch** and **via SSH**
  (`watch -c colors`) - in prints **only bold**.

I don't understand why the combination of the **watch** and doing it via **ssh** is making it print only bold and ignore the green. am I missing something?

What is the problem here?

Comment: maybe your `$TERM` is getting in the way? Check if it is set to a color-compatible value like `screen-256color` (if such applies)

Comment: in both my machine and the server the `$TERM` value is `xterm-256color`

Comment: Can you try this in turn with two different machines to figure out on wich side of the connection the problem is? (As what you are doing should work, at least it does on my machine)

Comment: You're right. it has something to do with this specific server. when connecting to my machine via ssh it worked. what in the server would make it not work? linux version? other things?

Comment: Can you check the watch version on the server in question? `watch -v` (For reference: I'm currently on `procps-ng 3.3.10`)

Comment: on the server `procps-ng 3.3.9`, on my machine `procps-ng 3.3.10`. I tried to look in the docs if they added something between the versions, couldn't find anything. you think its related?

Comment: Can you show how exactly you run it over ssh (with and without watch)?

For example, if you use ssh to login to the server and then run the program, it might run as expected. But if you use ssh with a remote command, you don't have a TTY attached by default and it will not show colours unless you use the -t switch with ssh.

Comment: I first logged in with SSH, and then run the command, like you said, so the TTY should be attached. log in first (username/password) -> then run the command, still doesn't work